# Using a char sentinel when scanning ints from user input

Tags: user-interface, user-input

I have a menu driven program where the user is prompted to enter as may integers as they would like in order to build a binary search tree--I have just started and am stuck getting out of reading their integers once they hit "Q"

```
    switch(inputOption){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You've selected to create a new binary tree." + "\n");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String again;
            String tempInput;
            Boolean repeat = true;
            try{
                System.out.println("Please enter as many integers as you'd like, hit 'Q' when you are finished." + "\n");
                do{

                    tempInput = scan.next();
                    if(tempInput != "Q"){
                        integerInput = Integer.parseInt(tempInput);
                        repeat = true;
                    }
                    else
                        repeat = false;

                }while(repeat);
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){}
```

Any ideas on how I can get it to recognize the 'Q'?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if(!tempInput.equals("Q"))
```

rather than

```
if(tempInput != "Q")
```

Java strings don't work with the comparison operators.

Comment: Ahhh yes-- it's hard to get C++ out of brain after it's been drilled in!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding (|| "q") could possibly help. You don't give much information though. For example have you dropped in with debugger and analyzed the actual value of tempInput to be sure it's actually "Q" ? If so then maybe try casting to character, or trimming any extra white spaces or special characters that it might contain.

More info would be better :-D